# Change text based on select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Full Disclosure: I am bad at javascript.

I'm trying to write something that takes the value of a select box (in this case, it contains a list of themes the user can choose from), compares it against an array containing all the themes allowed, and display a preview link to the user.

Below is some select code.

My Array containing the preview links:

```
var themePreview = [];
themePreview[0] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.trafficgettingblogs.com/?preview=1&template=arclite&stylesheet=arclite&TB_iframe=true&width=1000&height=700" class="thickbox thickbox-preview">Preview Arclite</a>';
themePreview[1] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.trafficgettingblogs.com/?preview=1&template=arras&stylesheet=arras&TB_iframe=true&width=1000&height=700" class="thickbox thickbox-preview">Preview Arras</a>';
themePreview[2] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.trafficgettingblogs.com/?preview=1&template=carrington-blog&stylesheet=carrington-blog&TB_iframe=true&width=1000&height=700" class="thickbox thickbox-preview">Preview Carrington Blog</a>';
```

My jQuery attempting to get the select box value and display a preview link:

```
$('select #selectedTheme').change(function() {
    //document.write('test'); // Try to see if I'm selecting what I need.
    $('#previewTheme').value() = themePreview[$('#selectedTheme option:selected').value()];
});
```

The select box has an ID of `selectedTheme`.

I'm not getting any errors, but I don't seem to be selecting the select box.

I am sure this is a very simple problem. I'm trying to improve my javascript skills. Rather unsuccessfully, it seems.

Comment: Show the code for your select input element.  That will show us the values of the select element, plus it's id so we can see if that jQuery selector will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment in your code doesn't do anything.

This should work:

```
$('#previewTheme').html( themePreview[$('#selectedTheme option:selected').value()] );
```

i.e. `html()` returns the current content of an element, `html(x)` replaces it with `x`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had also forgotten about WordPress using jQuery in no conflict mode. I appreciate the help, Aaron.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just get the value of the select, rather than the value of a specific option. Ie, change $('#selectedTheme option:selected').value() to $('#selectedTheme').val()

Comment: Thanks Joel. I used your method of selecting the value of the select box.